# Deployment fail record page

Tags: deployment, error

When i try run deployment appears this error, anyone know what is this?
error: invalid property [rowstodisplay] in component [force:relatedlistcontainer]
[[image: error detail]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IomRg.png)

i think this happened because i inserted in 2 pages layout(badge, rewards) with this lightning component:

[image: code]
I don't know if this happens for the lack of some "implements"

Comment: Could you please [edit] the text of the error into the body of your question as well?

Comment: Are you using Related list single component to show parent record on lightning page?

Comment: Is that possible that you try to deploy a changeset from sandbox on Summer19 into production on Spring19 org? That seems to be an new property